# How to play MP3 files with Chinese filename

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using python package **playsound 1.2.2** to play mp3 files. Everything is OK until I tried to play sound files with Chinese characters. It throw an error

> Error 275 for command:
> open "c:\temp\x1_好的.mp3" alias playsound_0.4552274050349264
> Cannot find the specified file.  Make sure the path and filename are correct.

Here is my code:

```
import os
from playsound import playsound


filename = 'c:\\temp\\x1_好的.mp3'
#filename = 'c:\\temp\\x1.mp3'
if os.path.exists(filename):
    print('ok')
    playsound(filename)
else:
    print('file not exists')
```

How do I deal with this? I'm using python version 3.8.8 on a Windows 7 OS.

Comment: temporarily rename the file before playing maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Mac but got curious about this. Looks like a file name encoding issue.

So, there's a related [issue/patch](https://github.com/TaylorSMarks/playsound/issues/29), mainly from

```
command = ' '.join(command).encode(getfilesystemencoding())
```

to:

```
command = ' '.join(command).encode('utf-16')
```

which is now in the [latest version (1.3.0)](https://github.com/TaylorSMarks/playsound/blob/v1.3.0/playsound.py#L55) also. I think you could try upgrading the package version from `1.2.2` (June 2017) to `1.3.0` (July 2021):

```
pip install playsound==1.3.0
```

Comment: As much as I want to use the 1.3 version, the problem is that I'm having a lot issues on production side so we use 1.2.2..